# authorize.net recurring billing

Tags: payment, authorize.net, billing, recurring

Need to integrate authorize.net payment gateway with my web application.

We need a Recurring billing subscription with single trial period (say 200$) and 10 monthly payments(100$). But there is a chance of having a different payment amount(say 125$) inbetween monthly payments and remaining installments may be or may not be changed. Current Update subscrition API allows us to update remaining payments but does not allows us to have a trial period in between. Kindly suggest me how to deal with this. Also heared of "Customer Profile" API ., will this help me?.

Use case Scenario:

assume an insurance policy worth 1200$ is purchased by an user. which will be charged from user like 200$ as downpayment(first payment/month) and remaining 1000$ in 10 installments (100$ per month). There is a chance where this policy can be endorsed in between payments by the user and the policy worth can increase or decrease (1200$ may turn up to 1500$ or may turn down to 1000$). In this case, on the month of endorsement there will be an downpayment (say 150$) to be charged and remaining payments may be updated to a constant amount(say 120$).

Thanks in advance,

Suresh babu R

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)

Comment: am not asking for the code snippet. So far i've gone through the Authorize.net API documentation. I have found API's that will help me seperately. But i need to do as mentioned in above scenario. I just need API/method suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I got this back from Authorize.net Developer advocate.,

Hi @sureshrb3,

If you have the customer profiles feature turned on for your account, then when you create a subscription, you'll get in the response a customer profile ID and a payment profile ID. Then, if you want to charge the card associated with the subscription in between subscription payments, you can create a transaction using the profile information in place of the card information (as detailed in the Charge a Customer Profile documentation).

So in your use case, you would just do a one time charge of the customer profile for the new down payment, then update the subscription for the correct amount of the remaining transactions.
-Aaron

This can be useful.

Thanks,
Suersh Babu R